# Excel export with row count 100k - 1Mio

Tags: excel, report, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2015

Our customer wants Excel exports with a varying rowset count ranging from 400.000 to 1 million rows.
The current limit for Excel exports is 100.000. 
I thought of creating a custom solution for this problem.

**Approach:**
A custom button in the UI, which opens Views for selection with row counts > 100k only, all other views will be covered by the default export functionality.
Setting the max row count in the DB table does not work as desired and it is not recommended/supported by Microsoft.

Are there any hands on for developing custom solutions for CRM 2015?

A paid solution is also an option.

[CRM2015 - Export data to Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/export-data-to-excel.aspx)

> Do you need to analyze your data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM and
>   convert that data into actionable items that help you drive more
>   sales? Now you can do this when you export your data to Microsoft
>   Excel or Excel Online to do a quick data analysis. Also, analyzing
>   large datasets is not a problem because you can export up to 100,000
>   rows of data.

[image]

Comment: Your customer wants Excel but needs PowerBI. Or is this meant for re-import ?

Comment: Our customer is using CRM2015, he has created some views for reports in CRM. And one report has over 400k of rows. Now when he clicks on "Export" or "Download", I don't know the exact naming of the button/link, then sometimes the report gets downloaded with all 400k of lines, but most of the time not. So the question here is, should I develop a custom CRM solution for that? Any ideas?

Comment: PowerBI looks like a data visualization tool...

Comment: For that amount of records, trying to have a "live" report isn't really an option. You might have to look at a data-warehousing solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I believe this is misunderstanding regarding rows number limitation for Excel - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3 (Worksheet size 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns)

By default there is a limit of rows number to export (30000 if I'm not wrong) from CRM but it can be fixed using for example this tool - https://orgdborgsettings.codeplex.com/

Comment: The problem is not related to Excel but to the CRM System!